# Embeding Facebook post to wordpress website is not working

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I want to embed facebook post to wordpress website. So I have created facebbok app and get APP ID and APP Secret. But when I try to get Access token using Graph API, I am not able to get it Here is screen shot of it http://prntscr.com/jqyvp7

Please help.

Comment: Massively unclear what you are talking about. (Please go read [ask].) If by “embedding” you mean use the Embedded Posts plugin Facebook provides, then what are you even talking about regarding permissions … this doesn’t need any?

Answer (score 0):

for embedding the facebook post in [WordPress](https://www.hindiaudionotes.in), you don't need any plugin, just click on the corner of any facebook post and click on embed, get the code and paste it in the code in the text area of any post, or you can also embed in the sidebar using html widget.